# Change custom control's appearance dynamically from its children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, custom-controls

I am creating a WPF touchscreen keyboard using the [InputSimulatorCore](https://github.com/cwevers/InputSimulatorCore) NuGet package. I have created a `Keyboard` custom control which is basically a grid containing several `KeyboardButton` custom controls.

First I created a custom control that can contain an image and some text as a basis for my `KeyboardButton` custom control.

```cs
public class ImageTextButton : Button
{
    // Constructors
    static ImageTextButton() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageTextButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageTextButton)));

    // Dependency properties
    public string ItemName { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemNameProperty = ...;
    public virtual ImageSource Source { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = ...;
    public double ImageHeight { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty = ...;
    public double ImageWidth { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty = ...;
    public Brush EllipseFill { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EllipseFillProperty = ...;
    public Brush FontColor { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontColorProperty = ...;

    public static P FindVisualParent<P>(DependencyObject dep) where P : DependencyObject
    {
        while (dep != null)
        {
            if ((dep is Visual) || (dep is System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D))
            {
                if (dep is P)
                {
                    return (dep as P);
                }
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }
            else
            {
                dep = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }
        }
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Next I inherited from `ImageTextButton` like this to create a basic `KeyboardButton` control that can call on an `InputSimulator` object to send key presses.

```cs
public class KeyboardButton : ImageTextButton
{
    protected Keyboard _keyboard;
    protected InputSimulator _sim = new InputSimulator();
    public ImageSource SourceNormal { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceNormalProperty = ...;
    public ImageSource SourceShift { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceShiftProperty = ...;
    public virtual bool Shifted { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShiftedProperty = ...;

    static KeyboardButton() { }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this._keyboard = FindVisualParent<Keyboard>(this);
    }
}
```

Then I defined a `CharacterOutputButton` that can send actual key presses as if the user typed on a keyboard:

```cs
public class CharacterOutputButton : KeyboardButton
{
    public VirtualKeyCode OutputCode { ... } // From the InputSimulator NuGet
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputCodeProperty = ...;
    public string Output { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputProperty = ...;
    public string OutputShift { ... }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputShiftProperty = ...;

    static CharacterOutputButton() { }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        // Sets the click event, is there a better way to do this?
        Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            _keyboard.Target.Focus();
            if (OutputCode > 0)
            {
                _sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(OutputCode);
            }
            else
            {
                _sim.Keyboard.TextEntry(Output);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, I wanted to implement the `CapsLockKey` custom control that also inherits from `KeyboardButton` in order to toggle caps lock:

```cs
public class CapsLockKey : KeyboardButton
{
    public override ImageSource Source // Update property when it's called?
    {
        get => NativeMethods.GetKeyState((ushort)VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL) > 0 ? SourceNormal : SourceShift;
        set => base.Source = NativeMethods.GetKeyState((ushort)VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL) > 0 ? SourceNormal : SourceShift;
    }

    static CapsLockKey() { }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            _sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL);
            if (NativeMethods.GetKeyState((ushort)VirtualKeyCode.CAPITAL) > 0)
            {
                Source = SourceNormal;
            }
            else
            {
                Source = SourceShift;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are a lot of remnants of my previous tries (properties such as `Shift` and `Shifted`) to implement a style change when the Caps Lock key was pressed, but to no avail.

I guess I have two concrete questions:

1. How can I dynamically update the style of my Character Output buttons when Caps Lock is pressed?
2. How can I maintain this state if I change the style of my keyboard, for example to rearrange the keys to match a different keyboard layout (QWERTY vs AZERTY)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VisualStateManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to dynamically transitioning between different visual states for your control:

```
if (someElement.IsCapsLockPressed)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(rect, "SomeState", true);
}
else
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(rect, "SomeOtherState", true);
}
```

Comment: @JansthcirlU: Did you try to use `VisualStateManager`?